# Get json file from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Get json file from textarea, Where the location of this code error, why can not read json

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('textarea').change(function(){
        var fa=[ $('textarea').val() ];
    var sjson =[JSON.stringify(fa)];
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < sjson.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append('<td>' + sjson[i].day + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td>' + sjson[i].open + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td>' + sjson[i].close + '</td>');
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});});
```

[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/failasuf/y8zh3m4t/11/)

Comment: `sjson[i]` is a .... string..... stringify makes a string. If you wanted to convert some JSON that is inside a textarea you would use JSON.parse on it's value which would make it into an object if it is valid JSON

Comment: this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/y8zh3m4t/12/?

Comment: thaks for the Explanation, it help @PatrickEvans

Comment: yes that what i want @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('textarea').change(function(){
        var fa="["+$('textarea').val()+"]";
    var sjson =jQuery.parseJSON(fa);
    var tr;
    $.each(sjson,function(key,value){
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append('<td>' + value.day + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td>' + value.open + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td>' + value.close + '</td>');
        $('table').append(tr)
    });
   
});});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>{
  "day": "sun",
  "open": "7:00",
  "close": "18:00"
 },
 {
  "day": "mon",
  "open": "8:00",
  "close": "18:00"
 }, {
  "day": "fri",
  "open": "9:00",
  "close": "17:00"
 }

</textarea>

<table></table>
```